# How to automate Windows 10 configuration into script properly?

Tags: windows, powershell, script, windows-registry, automation

I am trying to automate configuration for Windows 10 system.

For a better understanding of my aim: recently I have written down all the commands while setting up Arch Linux into a script and now I can run it and the system would be configured from the fresh installation in seconds more or less. Now I am trying to do the same with Windows.

I had an idea to do the following:

- dump the whole registry
- then configure taskbars, desktop, menu, file explorer, the whole settings etc.
- dump the whole registry again
- make a diff and do a kind of PowerShell script for that

But after I did a small test - same steps, just changed 1 setting in file explorer, 1 setting in the taskbar, and 1 option in Settings - I got a bloat of changes in a registry. Some of them are just some time related updates, there is a bloat from caching, and some registry entries that I cannot identify if they are related to my changes...

So my scenario is useless I guess...

Someone can propose something better?

Microsoft Account Sync is in no way, despite privacy reasons, it would not migrate configuration between different users and this is my need too.

Comment: You might want to put some settings into Group Policies and remove things from the script, etc. process. Injecting into the registry with a DIFF assuming you dump all the DIFF back into the registry could be troublesome if you are not sifting through and cleaning up reg changes you should not apply. I would try to work it out with sysprep for clones, unattend.xml for some levels of automation, a PowerShell and/or batch commands script post OS spin up configs but PowerShell is the way to go. We'd likely need to see all your scripted configs and a dump of the reg diff to answer less broadly.

Comment: Capture an image of the system then deploy that instead of attempting to do something that nobody attempts to do and (load the entire registry key from another system) which won't be possible.

Comment: The way I do it is install windows, on first boot at the blue oobe screen hit CTRL+SHIFT+F3 to go into audit mode. Make all the changes to the system in this mode, create an answer file with System Image Preparation Manager making sure you apply the "copy user profile" step inside the Specialize area of the answer file. This will ensure ALL settings applied are carried across to all future users. Then run sysprep using that answer file. Finally, capture an image of that hard drive before it runs the first boot and use that image to apply onto all other machines.